# Simple C function to MIPS instructions

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I have a simple c function that I need to convert to MIPS instructions for a homework assignment.

The function is:

```
int load(int *ptr) {
     return *ptr;
}
```

my MIPS instruction I've come up with is:

```
load:
     move $v0,$a0
     jr $ra
```

Is this correct?

Comment: have you tried running it? did it work?

Comment: Your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751463/how-is-this-mips-assembly-conversion-of-this-c-program) ended with `j $ra`; this ends with `jr $ra`.  Is the difference important?

Comment: normally I use MARS to test my work but at the moment I'm away from my primary computer and I don't have the ability to test

Comment: according to my textbook, 'jr' is the correct syntax. I must have made a typo - I'm very tired ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyze the function for a second.

First of all, what are the types of everything involved here?

- `ptr` is a pointer to an `int`.
- the return value should be of type `int`.

Next, what does the function do with this?

- dereferences the `int` pointer (i.e., reads the `int` value that the pointer is pointing to) `ptr` and returns that value.

Next consider what your code is doing.

- you moved the argument to the return value.
- return from the function.

Is this correct?

I'd say no.  You've essentially returned the pointer, not the value that the pointer was pointing to.

What can you do about it?

Well remember the types that we're dealing with here and what you did with it.  You have your argument (of type `int *`) and you return that (of type `int`).  The types do not match.  What did we do in the C program?  We dereferenced the pointer to get the value.  In other words, converted the `int *` to an `int`.  You need to do the same.