# How can we dereference a pointer in assembly code (MIPS)?

Tags: assembly, mips

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752401/simple-c-function-to-mips-instructions?rq=1) and I would like to know how can we dereference the pointer to int?
This is the code:

```
int load(int *ptr) 
{
    return *ptr;
}
```

Now, I know that $a0 contains the pointer. So that's the address of an integer, which we need to return.

Comment: What is the purpose of the proposed jump?

Comment: Now that I think about it, it's completely wrong..@JensBjörnhager

Comment: @Chris well I actually don't know anything about MIPS, but that seems about right..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MIPS, you dereference a pointer contained in register $a0 like this:

```
LW $v0, 0($a0)
JR $ra
```

Comment: So now $v0 contains the binary equivalent of the integer that ptr points to, right?